# SSRS Remote Database Connection Issue

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

I have installed SSRS 2008 R2 on Windows 2012 server. It is up and running. In the Configuration Manager, I have set it to point to remote Database on same network.

Then on my own PC (also on network) I open Report Manager website. I can see all reports fine. However, I get an error when attempting to run report. I then click on Datasource giving error and get this...
[image]

I have checked the domain server and the server hosting SSRS is added. 
In SSRS Configuration Manager, the Authentication Type is `Service Credentials`, and Username is `domain\SQLService`. When I test the Database connection from here, all is ok.

Any ideas why this is not working? Looks like Kerberos is not the issue.
Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think Kerberos isn't the problem?  Have you tried using this? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Comment: I didn't think Kerberos is the issue when using Service Account? Anyway, I have installed Kerberos Configuration Manager on the server hosting SSRS. I then attempt to connect to the remote Database through this. I tried my own login and then tried sa but get this error... _There was a permission issue accessing required services_. Thanks

Comment: I ran this query on the old server(SSRS2005) I am migrating from: `select auth_scheme from sys.dm_exec_connections where session_id=@@spid`, and it returns **SQL** rather than **Kerberos**. Yet no issues with remote database from here. Also I ran `setspn -l domain\serviceaccount`on the domain controller and the new server is listed.

Comment: OK. Looks like issue with my account for some reason. Kerberos all ok but when I try setting credentials on DataSource to `domain\serviceaccount`I get _permissions granted to mySSRSserver\Administrator are insufficient (rsaccessdenied)_. I do not know why it thinks I am using SSRS server admin login when logging in from my own PC?? Tested on other user pcs and works fine!